# Backbone without Hashes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

I think I'm trying to use Backbone in an unintended way, and I couldn't really find much on it. Basically I have a Rails app that is serving up the views. I want to keep the regular navigation (as in page reloading), but let backbone see the route and setup certain parts of the templates on that page, handle the models, and all of that good stuff. So basically I'm using Backbone to handle all of my complicated javascript without making it a "single page app". Would enabling PushState break my absolute paths in older browsers? eg: "http://localhost:3000/projects" matching the route "projects".

Answer (score 0):

PushState will not work in old browsers like IE6, but you could use different technique, for example you could use jQuery selectors and check whether you're on the particular page:

```
if ($('#login-page').length > 0) {
  // we're on the login page
  // ..initialize login page related backbone collections and views
}
```

..or you could store action/controller name somewhere in the html using data attribute: `<body data-action="edit" data-controller="post">` and check it in javascript `va4 $body = $('body'); if ($body.data('action') == 'edit' && $body.data('controller') == 'posts') {}` etc.

..or you could have separate js file for each action/controller pair and include it on demand.